# Neo4j issue with enforcing indexes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm running into an issue where I'm enforcing the use of an index in a Cypher batch query,

```
UNWIND {rows} AS row
MATCH (s:Entity)
USING INDEX s:Entity(uuid)
WHERE s.uuid = row.source
MATCH (t:Entity)
USING INDEX t:Entity(uuid)
WHERE t.uuid = row.target
MATCH (s)-[r:CONSUMED]->(t)
DELETE r
```

where `row.source` and `row.target` and both UUID strings. The issue is I get the error, `ERROR - Cannot use index hint in this context`.

If I augment the query to merely return the relationship for a specific source and target node in the Neo4j UI, i.e.

```
MATCH (s:Entity)
USING INDEX s:Entity(uuid)
WHERE s.uuid = '04bc79e1-a836-11e6-b841-22000bcec6a9'
MATCH (t:Entity)
USING INDEX t:Entity(uuid)
WHERE t.uuid = 'a245f46a-a837-11e6-b841-22000bcec6a9'
MATCH (s)-[r:CONSUMED]->(t)
RETURN r
```

no error is thrown and the relationship is returned, and thus I'm somewhat perplexed what the issue could be?

Comment: which version are you on? this should be fixed in newer versions

Comment: I actually tried it on the 3.1.0-M13-beta3 browser, and I still got the error.

Comment: @MichaelHunger See my updated answer. This behavior in recent neo4j versions seems to be a bug with the code that checks whether `USING INDEX` is allowed.

Comment: @MichaelHunger we're using 3.0.3 Community edition.

Comment: I have submitted [Issue 8463](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/8463) for the `USING INDEX` error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[UPDATED]

Your second query also changed the `WHERE` clauses, which is why it worked.

neo4j does not currently support *using the `USING INDEX` clause* for an index that will be used to compare property values to each other (as you do in your first query).

*Note: the latest versions of neo4j are actually able to use the index in that scenario, but if you try to specify the `USING INDEX` clause as a hint, neo4j will complain. This is probably a bug. I have submitted [Issue 8463](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/8463) for this.*

However, neo4j has no problems with the `USING INDEX` clause when the index is used to compare a property value to an identifier or a literal (as you do in your second query).

Luckily, there is a simple workaround. You can just create identifiers for the property values and use those identifiers instead. For example, see how the `WITH` clause is used here:

```
UNWIND {rows} AS row
WITH row.source AS source, row.target AS target
MATCH (s:Entity)
USING INDEX s:Entity(uuid)
WHERE s.uuid = source
MATCH (t:Entity)
USING INDEX t:Entity(uuid)
WHERE t.uuid = target
MATCH (s)-[r:CONSUMED]->(t)
DELETE r
```

Comment: I was not aware of this. Does this apply for all cases of index lookup, including when MATCHing with a row property from a CSV import? Most of the examples I see for that use the row property directly instead of aliasing first, so that would mean indexes are never used? Including for merges?

Comment: I would not expect such queries to be able to use indexes.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a more complete picture of the issue. So, I understand now that my last comment is not generally true. With recent versions of neo4j, such queries can use indexes in that scenario, but only if the planner chooses to use indexes. You cannot use the `USING INDEX` clause to give a hint.